# How to write a string based rule, e.g. If "Name" contains 'NRG'

Tags: qgis, style, rule-based

I have created a field called 'Name' in QGIS and I wish to create a rule-based style for a gridded vector. The grids are either 'NEP1' or 'NEP1NRG' etc. with values to 5000+. I want a rule to colour the grid polygons with 'NRG' in the 'Name' field one way, and those without this in the name another. 
E.g. If "Name" contains 'NRG' then adhere to style rule, if not then another.

I have tried variations of LIKE but not sure this is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

`Name LIKE 'NRG%'`